# Counter-example to “Every RV has a CDF.”

Tags: probability-theory

I’ve seen the statement that all RVs have CDFs and vice versa in many textbooks. 
The way they show is by simply constructing $F_X(x) = P(X \in (\infty, x))$.

But that assumes $\forall x\in\mathbb R: (\infty, x) \in \mathcal F$, which isn’t necessarily true for all $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb R$. Thus, haven’t we found a counter-example?

To be explicit, the definition of RVs I’m using is: measurable functions from the sample space of a  probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ to any measurable space $(A, \mathcal A)$.

Comment: There are many similarly-titled questions, but imo this is not a duplicate. I’m asking about a specific counter-example. I could try to edit the title to make it sound more distinct if needed.

Comment: The term 'random variable' has a fixed universally accepted meaning and what you are trying to do is to change its meaning.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think you’re definitely right in that we’re working with different definitions of RVs. I edited the question to state mine. Could you state yours? I know you mentioned it’s a universally accepted meaning, but somehow I seem to have missed it in the references I consulted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have defined is often called a *random element* of $A$. In contrast, *random variables* are usually defined as measurable functions from a probability space to $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. With this restriction, the definition $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$ is always valid.

If a random variable is defined as measurable map from a measure space into a measurable space the we can associate with it what is called the induced measure: $\nu (A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$ for $A \in \mathcal A$. Sometimes this is also called the distribution of $X$. It so happens that in the case $A=\mathbb R$ with Borel sigma algebra there is a one-to-one correspondence between induced measures and the functions $F_X$.

Comment: Hmm… the definitions I’ve seen only required $X$ map to a measurable space $(A, \mathcal A)$, not necessarily $A = \mathbb R$ and not necessarily $\mathcal A = \mathcal B (\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference? I’d love to dig deeper.

Comment: In that case you are asking about existence of what? Can you give a precise definition of the term 'random variable' and the  term 'distribution function'?

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal What you have defined is often called a random element of $A$.  In any case please see if my revised answer is clear.

Comment: Ahhh random elements vs random variables. The text I was using didn’t distinguish. This makes sense—thank you!